# How to paste text from the clipboard into a text field

Tags: python, clipboard, copy-paste

How can I paste a string into a text field, like for example the Windows search bar or a text editor using Python?

I searched a lot for this, but all I can find is hundreds of questions asking how to copy to the clipboard or getting a string from the clipboard. What I want to do is paste from the clipboard into the active Window, as if I were pressing ctrl+v. If possible, I want to avoid the seemingly complicated way of emulating the actual low-level keyboard press.

Comment: try [autokey](https://github.com/guoci/autokey-py3)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows clipboard is considered IPC ([Inter process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)).
You can read some of the details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#base.using_the_clipboard_for_ipc).

In python you can use [this library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/clipboard/0.0.4) I think supporting major OS.
For linux specific are options like xclip but I think it's desktop environment dependent.